# Apache Hive Create Table in S3 Bucket Error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

I have set up Hive (version 3.1.2) and Hadoop (version 3.3.1) on my local machine in Linux on top of Java version [openjdk version "1.8.0_292"]. I also have an AWS S3 bucket set up.

I can connect to the s3 bucket and get a response from the commands below. I get a correct response with a list of the files in my bucket so I know I can connect.

```
hadoop fs -ls s3a://my-bucket-name/
aws s3 ls my-bucket-name
```

The problem I have is when I try to create a table in the S3 bucket using Hive. My Hive Query is as below. I am using Postgres as my Metastore database by the way. Installed locally on my machine.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_orders(id int, user_id int, guid string, url_domain string, price int, city string, latitude decimal(10,5), longitude decimal(10,5), zip int, is_delivered boolean, note string)
COMMENT 'user orders details'
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3a://my-bucket-name/';
```

I get the following error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

When I look at the hive logs, it is more verbose. This will be long but here we go.

```
Compiling command(queryId=ubuntu_20210811205002_86cab28f-ef5a-4e39-ae7b-30bb25d2ba1c): CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS hive_parquet
location 's3a://my-bucket-name/'
2021-08-11T20:50:02,888  INFO [e3cbda42-bb24-46f0-ace6-6183d92a2c36 main] ql.Driver: Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
2021-08-11T20:50:02,915 ERROR [e3cbda42-bb24-46f0-ace6-6183d92a2c36 main] ql.Driver: FAILED: SemanticException java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.toWriteEntity(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:2126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.toWriteEntity(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:2118)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.toWriteEntity(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:2114)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.DDLSemanticAnalyzer.addLocationToOutputs(DDLSemanticAnalyzer.java:4267)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.DDLSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeCreateDatabase(DDLSemanticAnalyzer.java:1346)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.DDLSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(DDLSemanticAnalyzer.java:510)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:659)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1826)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1773)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1768)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.compileAndRespond(ReExecDriver.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.run(ReExecDriver.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:188)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:402)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3467)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.tryQualifyPath(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:2153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.toWriteEntity(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:2123)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:135)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/Invoker.once(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/functional/CallableRaisingIOE;)Ljava/lang/Object; @118: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type 'com/amazonaws/AmazonClientException' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'com/amazonaws/SdkBaseException'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @118
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'org/apache/hadoop/util/functional/CallableRaisingIOE', 'com/amazonaws/AmazonClientException' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'com/amazonaws/AmazonClientException' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: bb00 0559 b200 0103 1206 04bd 0007 5903
    0x0000010: 2a53 b700 084e 013a 042c b900 0901 003a
    0x0000020: 052d c600 1f19 04c6 0016 2db6 000a a700
    0x0000030: 133a 0619 0419 06b6 000c a700 072d b600
    0x0000040: 0a19 05b0 3a05 1905 3a04 1905 bf3a 072d
    0x0000050: c600 1f19 04c6 0016 2db6 000a a700 133a
    0x0000060: 0819 0419 08b6 000c a700 072d b600 0a19
    0x0000070: 07bf 4e2a 2b2d b800 0ebf
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [42, 46] => handler: 49
    bci [25, 33] => handler: 68
    bci [25, 33] => handler: 77
    bci [88, 92] => handler: 95
    bci [68, 79] => handler: 77
    bci [0, 65] => handler: 114
    bci [68, 114] => handler: 114
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@49,{Object[#116],Object[#116],Object[#117],Object[#118],Object[#119],Object[#120]},{Object[#119]})
    same_frame(@61)
    same_frame(@65)
    full_frame(@68,{Object[#116],Object[#116],Object[#117],Object[#118],Object[#119]},{Object[#119]})
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@77,Object[#119])
    full_frame(@95,{Object[#116],Object[#116],Object[#117],Object[#118],Object[#119],Top,Top,Object[#119]},{Object[#119]})
    same_frame(@107)
    same_frame(@111)
```

I cannot figure this out despite several days spent on search engines. One thing I did notice was that my property `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` is currently set to `/user/hive/warehouse`. I am not sure whether it should also point to the s3 bucket.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of hadoop-aws are you using?

Comment: why are you creating table on the whole  bucket? Normally it should be table_name after bucket, because bucket is a bigger unit. Like this: LOCATION 's3a://my-bucket-name/user_orders', no last slash needed

Comment: I am using Hadoop version 3.3.1. I will try LOCATION 's3a://my-bucket-name/user_orders' now

Comment: I am using hadoop-aws-3.3.1.jar.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue. It looks like there might be an issue with Hadoop 3.3.1 running in conjunction with Hive 3.1.2. I downgraded my versions based on the [Hortonworks HDP 3.1.5 Release Notes](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/release-notes/content/comp_versions.html) and everything just worked! So one thing to consider is version compatibility between Hadoop and Hive.